# Seletor de negação do .gitignore não funcionando

Tags: git

Tenho um repositório onde eu coloco exercícios feitos em *C*, quando compilados, geram um executável sem extensão(no Linux, no Windows gera um arquivo "*.exe*"). Quero apenas que apareçam os arquivos com extensão *.c* nas pastas, porém ele ignora também qualquer arquivo *.c*

Meu **.gitignore** está assim:

```
    /*

    !/*.c

    *.exe
```

Comment: não entendi a sua pergunta. Por favor, explique melhor. Isto está acontecendo ao realizar o envio dos arquivos para um repositório Git remoto? ```( git push )```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu arquivo `.gitignore` está funcionando como você deseja no diretório raiz do repositório. Porém, se os arquivos desejados estão dentro de sub-pastas, você deve adicionar essas sub-pastas também em uma negação do `.gitignore`.

Experimente o seguinte:

```
*
!*/
!*.c
```

Que dá o seguinte resultado:

```
$ ls pastanova/
abacate.c  abacate.exe*  b.c  b.exe*

$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   a.c
        new file:   pastanova/b.c

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        pastanova/abacate.c
```

Que é o resultado desejado. Para mais informações veja [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9049909/10746978) (em inglês).

Obs: Sua última linha `*.exe` era redundante.